# Custom Fn shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, keyboard-accelerators

Is it possible to make a shortcut with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key? As a example (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>) for open a program.

Have somebody a idea how to add this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fn keys alter the keyboard signal before it reaches the computer. You can try it yourself using `xev`: there's no output when you press the Fn key alone. So no, you can't add new Fn + key shortcuts, but you can bind actions to the existing keyboard functions.